# xcode 4.3 - how to create a data model from existing classes

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, entities

in xcode 3 when you added a data model (a .xcdatamodel file) you had an option to choose existing classes to create entities from.

how do you do this in xcode 4?

i found this excellent tutorial (http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/) which covers pretty much everything on adding core data to an existing project, the only thing that is missing (because it is from 2009) is an answer to my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your datamodel click an Entity.  Then go to File-> New File -> Core Data -> NSManageObject subclass.

Comment: The question is referring to the other way around.

Comment: I believe the feature has since been removed in XCode 4.  An option could be to have a separate installation of XCode 3 to perform the operation, and then add it manually into the XCode 4 project.

Comment: thanks @AdamJohnson, how exactly do i add it manually to the xcode 4 project? if i open the object in xcode 3, and add the data model while generating entities from existing classes that should do it, no? i just save the project and open it from xcode 4..

Comment: @AdamJohnson - Are you sure that such a nice feature has now been stripped off? Isnt there any direct way now to convert an existing project to coredata supported project then? This definitely leaves Xcode 4 handicapped of a good feature if it is so.